# Is it possible to sync data fields width with heading widths?

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

I have a report that shows data on one or two cities. The data is numeric and narrow while the city names can be longer.
I have one query/repeating frame for the city names (and some other info), and another query/repeating frame for the multi-row data.
For each city there are 5 numeric values.

With short city names the columns align fine, but with longer names the name columns get expande more and more to the right, while the data columns remain short and to the left.

I don't think it's possible to anchor the fields together, as they're in different frames.
Anchoring the frames can make the value frame centered under the city frame but the columns are no more aligned.

My layout principle, here with 3 values per city. Both frames are only repeating downwards, but the city frame will only give one row.

```
 ___________________________________________________
| Some label                                        | rep. frame
|  _____   _____    _____   _____    _____   _____  |
| |     | |     |  |     | |     |  |     | |     | |
| |City1| |City2|  |City1| |City2|  |City1| |City2| |
| |_____| |_____|  |_____| |_____|  |_____| |_____| |
|___________________________________________________|
 ___________________________________________________
|  _____   _____    _____   _____    _____   _____  | rep. frame
| |     | |     |  |     | |     |  |     | |     | |
| |ValA1| |ValA2|  |ValB1| |ValB2|  |ValC1| |ValC2| |
| |_____| |_____|  |_____| |_____|  |_____| |_____| |
| more rows...                                      |
|___________________________________________________|
```

With longer names the layout turns into this:

```
 ________________________________________________________________________
| Some label                                                             |
|  ______   ___________    ______   ___________    ______   ___________  |
| |      | |           |  |      | |           |  |      | |           | |
| |Longer| |Even longer|  |Longer| |Even longer|  |Longer| |Even longer| |
| |______| |___________|  |______| |___________|  |______| |___________| |
|________________________________________________________________________|
 ___________________________________________________
|  _____   _____    _____   _____    _____   _____  |
| |     | |     |  |     | |     |  |     | |     | |
| |ValA1| |ValA2|  |ValB1| |ValB2|  |ValC1| |ValC2| |
| |_____| |_____|  |_____| |_____|  |_____| |_____| |
| more rows...                                      |
|___________________________________________________|
```

If there is no other way I might try to expand the value-query with an initial union to also fetch the selected cities. Then the city names and values will be printed by the same field. Finally I can remove the city-fields and turn the top repeating frame into a regular.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION`, as you said, might be one option.

Another one is to do it in paper layout editor: for both repeating frames, expand all fields to their maximums (so that they fill the whole paper width) and set their **horizontal elasticity** to "Fixed" (so that the wouldn't expand to the right any more, but they won't *shrink* either).

You'd probably want to leave **vertical elasticity** to "Variable", just in case if some value is longer than the field width allows.

Frames' would horizontally also be "Fixed" (as they probably already are), but will be vertically "Variable".

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried a UNION to get the names and values in the same frame.
At least I lerned something...

The result was this

```
 ________________________________________________________________________
| Some label                                                             |
|  ______   ___________    ______   ___________    ______   ___________  |
| |      | |           |  |      | |           |  |      | |           | |
| |Longer| |Even longer|  |Longer| |Even longer|  |Longer| |Even longer| |
| |______| |___________|  |______| |___________|  |______| |___________| |
|  _____   _____    _____   _____    _____   _____                       |
| |     | |     |  |     | |     |  |     | |     |                      |
| |ValA1| |ValA2|  |ValB1| |ValB2|  |ValC1| |ValC2|                      |
| |_____| |_____|  |_____| |_____|  |_____| |_____|                      |
| more rows...                                                           |
|________________________________________________________________________|
```

As the end result of a report is an HTML `<table>` I guess I hoped the widest field value would dictate the width of that `<td>`. But Reports uses colspan to make rows unique...

So in the end I had to set the fields to fixed horizontal width and expand vertically. The width is set to "reasonable", as the maximum width would make the table ugly and hard to read.
I also added a "translation" of long city names to more "split friendly", like Stockholm to Stock-holm (or it might split like Stockhol-m).

Comment: OK then, I'm glad you fixed it. Thank you for letting us know!